# How Shall i set the Border of a DataGrid Cell based on a checkbox IsChecked Property

Tags: wpf

Please find the below style which i use to set the border of DataGridCell on Keyboard focus.

```
   <Style x:Key="DynamciEditableDataGridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultDataGridCellStyle}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True"/>
                  <!--How to add another condition which checks on the check box IsChecked property-->
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ActiveInputBorderBrush}"/>
                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
            </MultiTrigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource EditableBackgroundBrush}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

I need to have two conditions for setting border thickness and Border Brush.......

1) On KeyboardFocus inside the cell (this is working as per the above code)

2) On checkbox IsChecked property is True (checkbox is not a part of the datagrid but a control inside the same view)

please help me on achieving this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you do not include XAML of your CheckBox in your question, I assume it has a Name specified, then you can use `MultiDataTrigger` instead of `MultiTrigger` so that you can use `Binding` to listen to any property change of some other element:

```
<Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsKeyboardFocusWithin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=checkBox}" Value="True"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
                <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource ActiveInputBorderBrush}"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource EditableBackgroundBrush}"/>
        </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

I assume your CheckBox has Name of `checkBox`.